# Solution verification - $\log-$likelihood of multinomial probit model with $J$ alternatives

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, partial-derivative, standard-deviation, log-likelihood

The initial function is log-likelihood of multinomial probit model with $J$ alternatives:

$ ln \ell=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^{J-1} y_{ij} \cdot ln \Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})+ ({n_i-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}y_{ij}}) \cdot ln[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]$

Then, the first derivative of

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\beta_{kj}}\sum_{i=1}^N \left\{y_{ij} \cdot ln \Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})+ y_{iJ} \cdot ln\left[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})\right]\right\}$

would be

$\sum_{i=1}^N \left\{y_{ij} \dfrac{x_{ik}\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}{\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}- y_{iJ} \dfrac{x_{ik}\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}{1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}\right\}$

Can somene help me with the second derivative? I am aware that for each $\beta_{kj}$ I need to differentiate wrt every other $\beta_{kj}$:

$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\beta_{kj}\beta_{k'j'}}=\sum_{i=1}^N \left\{y_{ij} \dfrac{x_{ik}\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}{\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}- y_{iJ} \dfrac{x_{ik}\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}{1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}\right\}$

I know that there will be two cases where $j'=j$ and $j'\ne j$ and that derivative of the first fraction in the bracket when $j'=j$ would be

$-x_{ik'}x_{ik}y_{ij}\cdot\dfrac{(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})\cdot\phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}{\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}-x_{ik'}x_{ik}y_{ij}\cdot\dfrac{\phi^2(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}{\Phi^2(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}$.

Any help with the second derivative of the second fraction when $j'=j$ and both fractions when $j'$ not equal to $j$ would be very much appreciated.

---

*** EDIT: 2 ***
 this is my attempt of doing second derivative of the probit log-likelihood function:

The second derivative of the log-likelihood function should have the following form:

$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\beta_{kj}\beta_{k'j'}}=\sum_{i=1}^N\left\{y_ij\dfrac{\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})\cdot\varphi'(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})-\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})\cdot\Phi'(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}{\Phi^2(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}+y_{iJ}\dfrac{[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]\cdot\varphi'(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})-\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})\cdot[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi'(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]'}{[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]^2} \right\}$

Hence, the derivatives of the numerator and denominator will depend whether $j'=j$ (Case 1) or $j'\ne j$ (Case 2).

**Case 1 $j'=j$**

$\varphi'(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})=-x_{ik'}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj}\cdot\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})$

$\Phi'(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})=x_{ik'}\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})$

$[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]'=-x_{ik'}\cdot\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})$

**2) case $j'\ne j$**

$\varphi'(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})=0$

$\Phi'(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})=0$

$[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]'=-x_{ik'}\cdot\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj'})$

By substituting these terms in the main equation for the case (1) yields

$=-\sum_{i=1}^N\left\{y_{ij}\dfrac{(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})\cdot\phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}{\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}+y_{ij}\dfrac{\phi^2(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}{\Phi^2(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}+y_{iJ}\dfrac{(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})\cdot\phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}{[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]}+y_{iJ}\dfrac{\phi^2(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{jk})}{[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]^2}\right\}\cdot x_{ik}x_{ik'}$

By solving for case (2), first fraction is equal to $0$

$\sum_{i=1}^N\left\{y_{ij}\dfrac{\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})\cdot0-\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})\cdot0}{\Phi^2(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}+y_{iJ}\dfrac{[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]\cdot0-\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})\cdot(-x_{ik'})\cdot\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj'})}{[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]^2} \right\}$

And the result is

$=-\sum_{i=1}^N\left\{y_{iJ}\dfrac{\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})\cdot x_{ik'}\cdot\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj'})}{[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]^2} \right\}$

Is this correct?

Comment: The very first thing I notice is poor notation: in the first line, $k$ appears both as a free index and as a dummy index in a sum. So it is completely unclear what is meant.

Comment: @MPW I have edited my question. Hopefully, it will be clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

With the second fraction (although the working is the same as with the first fraction),

$$y_{ij}\cdot \dfrac{x_{ik}\cdot\varphi(\sum\limits_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}{1-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum\limits_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})}$$

just continue with the quotient rule as before. The denominator is just a sum of functions, and so presents no real problem.

As for the $j,j'$ issue, it makes no difference whether $j=j'$ or $j\ne j'$ - both cases can be differentiated in the same way. However, due to the nature of partial differentiation, if $j\ne j'$, then $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b_{j}}b_{j'}=0$ as $j$ and $j'$ can be considered to be independent from each other.

And the 'J' in $y_{iJ}$ should be in lowercase.

Comment: Could you please explain why in the document at the following link http://czep.net/stat/mlelr.pdf , page 13, the differentiation is different for $j'=j$ and $ j'\ne j$?

Comment: the partial is j and j' but you can't see it!

Comment: I have edited my question and provided possible solution of second order derivatives for second fraction. I would be very thankful for any suggestions/corrections.

Comment: @Navi; you have a common factor of $[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]$ top and bottom, so this could be cancelled

Comment: Not sure that I understand. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: i think you forgot to differentiate the RHS numerator one.

Comment: You mean numerator of first fraction?

Comment: yes. it just involves putting a dash above and to the right of the capital Phi symbol.

Comment: i've done it for you

Comment: But the derivative of $[1-\sum_{j=1}^{J-1}\Phi(\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{ik}\beta_{kj})]$ is wrong?

Comment: possibly, you can argue your derivative of $\phi$ is also wrong. In the paper you quoted the $\phi$ function is $e$, so I can't see how these disappear with partial differentiation.The chain rule should apply, but this means the function is practically unusable (which I've just spotted you've done in the next section - so you were just missing the apostrophe). Substitute these back into the main equation and it should simplify.

Comment: But here is the case with standard normal cdf ($\Phi$) and pdf ($\phi$) and the derivative of normal pdf $\phi'(t)=-t\phi(t)$. What am I missing? I only provided the derivatives of individual terms of second fraction. I will try to provide the final solution of substituting these terms in the main equation.

Comment: I have provided the final solution for the second derivative of the probit log-likelihood function under EDIT 2 of the main question. Please take a look when you have the time and tell me your comments.

Comment: is this a question or a paper. see arviv, take some tablets...

Comment: I have shortened my question. As for the second part of your comment, I don't know to what is reffered.